# How to set up a #link to later on a page, but aligning the target with the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I want to click the `about` section on my new website and when it scrolls down, instead of it sliding the about section up and aligning the top of the "about" section with the top of the screen, I want to align the bottom of the "about" section with the bottom of the screen.

I'm not sure if this has to be done with javascript or if it can be done with HTML.  What are your thoughts?

Here is the function used to scroll to the top. [( Here Is A JSFiddle )](http://goo.gl/oQOdxM)

```
//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Do I just change it to:

```
//jQuery for page scrolling (to bottom) feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollBottom: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: you will need javascript, HTML and CSS. Maybe have a look at jQuery which is a javascript library and will make many things in javascript a bit more easy

Comment: well, I know about those silly. :)  I was kind of just clarifying.  I'm more trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: If you're trying to figure out how post what code and markup you have and then we can try to help you solve the problem. Maybe setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I just added [(this JsFiddle)](http://goo.gl/j0DkKH) to the question above.

Comment: @AlexCory You need to include jquery UI in your fiddle in order to use that easing.  Your posted fiddle is blowing up on the animate and instead just doing the default behavior of the link as it never reaches the `preventDefault` line.  This is why it is a best practice to include the `preventDefault` first in your handler.  http://jsfiddle.net/YjgdS/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `scrollBottom`, so you'll need to calculate the appropriate `scrollTop`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var $section = $($anchor.attr('href'));
        var scrollPos = $section.offset().top + $section.outerHeight() - $(window).height();

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: scrollPos
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YjgdS/6/